# Cardinality of Cartesian product of Binary Sequences

Tags: elementary-set-theory, binary

Let $S = \{ s\mid s\text{ is an infinite binary sequence}\}$ be the [set of all infinite binary sequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323388/the-set-of-all-infinite-binary-sequences).

By [Cantor's Diagonal Argument](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument), $S$ is uncountable.

But does $|S \times S| = |S|$ also hold?

Comment: Your definition of $S$ is just $\{0,1\}$. How about you write *in exact and explicit* words what is $S$?

Comment: @Asaf Karagila Done.

Comment: If it is an uncountable set, why do you write it as $\{s_1, s_2,\ldots\}$ which seems to imply that it is countable? Also, again this is not how set-builder notation is used, and you got $S=\{0,1\}$ again.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila Can you please edit the question ro the correct form? Thanks.

Comment: Also, $S$ is often denoted by $2^\Bbb N$, or sometimes $2^\omega$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Simply separate each sequence into two sequences. If $s$ is a sequence, then we can decompose it to $u$ and $t$ such that $u(n)=s(2n)$ and $t(n)=s(2n+1)$. Namely, taking the even coordinates as the sequence $u$ and the odd coordinates as the sequence $t$.

It is not hard to check that the map $s\mapsto(u,t)$ as defined above is indeed a bijection between $S$ and $S\times S$.